# Div bootstrap background position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8REI.png)

I am having issues with this layout. I want to position a picture of an app right in the center of these boxes. it is important that the image is visible over the top and under the bottom of background for the sections with text. I have tried everything both as background and as normal image (position, z-index, etc.).
I am using bootstrap for col and row. I also needs this to look beautiful on mobile. I need design to look at attached picture, but with the picture in the middle in front of the background. Any suggestions?

Current code and CSS:

```
<center> 
<div class="margin50">
<section class="appfeatures section-spacing">
<div class="container_appfeatures">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-right"><h3 class="white">Headline</h3><br />text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 text-left"><img class="appicon_white" src="img/createtip_white.png" alt="Opret Tip Ikon"></div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-1 text-right"><img class="appicon_white" src="img/rank_white.png" alt="Rank List Ikon"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-left"><h3 class="white">Headline</h3><br />text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-right"><h3 class="white">Headline</h3><br />text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 text-left"><img class="appicon_white" src="img/feed_white.png" alt="Live Score Ikon"></div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-1  text-right"><img class="appicon_white" src="img/profile_white.png" alt="Eksperter Ikon"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-left"><h3 class="white">Headline</h3><br />text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>

</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
</center>


.appicon_white {
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
    }

.appfeatures {

background: rgb(102,204,153);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(102,204,153,1) 0%, rgba(30,130,76,1) 100%);
opacity: 0.5;
}


.container_appfeatures {
width: 80%;

}



.margin50 {
margin-top: 75px;
margin-bottom: 75px;
width:100%; 
height:100%;
background-image: url("../img/profile.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
padding-top:95px;
padding-bottom:95px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `col-md-offset-4` just `col-md-4` and your must use `<div class="row">` in every row. Here I updated your html code:

```
<center>
    <div class="margin50">
        <section class="appfeatures section-spacing">
            <div class="container_appfeatures">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 text-right">
                        <h3 class="white">Headline</h3>
                        <br />text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 text-center">
                        <img class="appicon_white" src="img/createtip_white.png" alt="Opret Tip Ikon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 text-center">
                        <img class="appicon_white" src="img/rank_white.png" alt="Rank List Ikon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 text-left">
                        <h3 class="white">Headline</h3>
                        <br />text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://path to your iphone image">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 text-right">
                        <h3 class="white">Headline</h3>
                        <br />text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 text-center">
                        <img class="appicon_white" src="img/feed_white.png" alt="Live Score Ikon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 text-center">
                        <img class="appicon_white" src="img/profile_white.png" alt="Eksperter Ikon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 text-left">
                        <h3 class="white">Headline</h3>
                        <br />text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</center>
```

CSS code updated:

```
.appicon_white {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.appfeatures {
    background: rgb(102, 204, 153);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(102, 204, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(30, 130, 76, 1) 100%);
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin: 170px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.container_appfeatures {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 75px auto;
}

.margin50 {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.margin50 img {
    max-width: 250px;
    width: 100%;
}

img.phone-middle {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/marksalvania/94uyLvp1/

then on your mobile/smaller view just add this on your media queries something like this:

```
.col-md-3 {
    text-align:left;
    font-size: 10px; /*just adjust this to your desired size*/
}

.col-md-1,
.margin50 {
    display:none; /*this is just optional if you just want hide icons on mobile view. Much better if you will hide the phone image on mobile view for sleek and clean layout.*/
}

.your-other-styles {
    /*add your other styles here*/
}
```

Comment: Double `.row` is not the way to Bootstrap.

Comment: Didn't see that, Yes you're right I just edit my code above. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks, but I am still having issues bringing the picture in front of the background color. What css do you suggest for this ?

Comment: @htobiassen See my updated code above and check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/marksalvania/94uyLvp1/ tell me if I got it right. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. I have tried with the updated code, but now picture is in the middle of the page. And not in the middle of the div/section.
I think the issue is that there also is other content of page and the solution you send would only work if this was only contant on page. Do you know how to place it only in the middle of the section even though there is other content on page ?

Comment: @MarkSalvania not sure if you see comment without tag. So I will just try to tag you :)

Comment: Hi!. did you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/marksalvania/94uyLvp1/ I updated my code above it is already at the middle of those 2 rows of contents only problem is it was affected by the opacity:0.5 of your .appfeatures. Have a great day! :)

Comment: Hi @MarkSalvania I have already tried the code. But the picture is showing in the middle of my page.. And not in the div :/
You can see what I mean here: https://tipyaapp.com/index.php

Comment: Great now I can see the live site, Check out my updated fiddle. this will now fix the issue for sure. https://jsfiddle.net/marksalvania/94uyLvp1/ and check my updated code above